# Precompiling Eigen Headers

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, precompiled-headers

I am building a C++ project using Eclipse on Windows OS, I am also using the Eigen Linear Algebra library. My problem is with the very slow compiling time of Eigen (about 50 sec).

I've tried these proposed solutions:

- [Precompiled headers in Eclipse](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/systemsbiology/staff/dyer/software/pchineclipse/): unfortunately didn't work with me
- [The Amazing Ruby: Precompiled Header Hack for Eclipse CDT](http://jdleesmiller.blogspot.de/2009/10/amazing-ruby-precompiled-header-hack.html#script): it reduced the compiling time with 5 sec
- `#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG`: it reduced the time with additional 3 seconds

I really need a solution for this, it's very unpractical to wait 47 sec each time I build the project to test something.

Any idea is deeply appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Precompiled header support is compiler-specific. Which compiler & version are you using? And what exactly didn't work from the first link?

Comment: @Angew. I am using Cygwin C++ Compiler -g3. Regarding the first link, I did my best to follow it but it gave me no results, nothing changed, I might have done a mistake in the step where it says "Then go to the miscellaneous option select the release configuration and add ... ". I wasn't sure how to construct my path in that shape.

Answer (score 2):

Eigen is a template library, meaning that the classes are defined based on the template parameters. I don't think that you would be able to precompile without letting the compiler know exactly all the possible classes you would need in your entire code base.

Alternatively, you could write a wrapper for Eigen and declare all the types you want and use that library. HOWEVER, you are likely to lose a lot of Eigen's advantages (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023342/writing-a-wrapper-for-eigen-without-templates), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968631/how-to-write-a-third-party-library-wrapper-class-around-expression-templates) and others).

Comment: It *is* possible to use precompiled headers to speed up template compilation, at least with compiler which do two-phase name lookup properly. It may not speed up the instantiation,but it will still save on the parsing. And with template code, there's usually a lot of parsing involved.

Comment: @Angew Fair enough. However, the second point is still valid, albeit dangerous for performance due to the loss of expression templates.